# Why One of the Arrays had an error checking when I tried to count the number of numbers in an array using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I tried to do something like counting how many occurances in an array and then saves those values on to Dictionary, but along the way there is one values that has wrong counts. When I did some tracing with the code I noticed that this value suddenly restarted the counting. Tried to search on the web but I didn't found it or I didn't search that deep.

Code :

```
listA = [11, 45, 8, 11, 101, 23, 45, 23, 45, 89, 101]
dictList = {
    
}

n = len(listA)

for i in range (0, n):
    total = 1
    if listA[i] not in dictList:
        dictList[listA[i]] = total
    else:
        for j in range (i, n):
            if listA[i] == listA[j]:
                total = total + 1
        dictList.update({listA[i] : total})

print(dictList)
```

The output it given :

```
{11: 2, 45: 2, 8: 1, 101: 2, 23: 2, 89: 1}
```

The correct output :

```
{11: 2, 45: 3, 8: 1, 101: 2, 23: 2, 89: 1}
```

Yes, it was just one variable that got wrong. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your second loop starts from `i`, meaning you are recounting the i'th element. You can start from `i + 1` instead. Note: You can solve this problem with one loop like the answer below.

Comment: I think Counter will be useful here 
 from collections import Counter

list_a = [11,55,11,22,1,2,2,3]

Counter(list_a)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I've tried to start the second loop using i+1 and it actually decreases the output values, all of them only had 1 occurance

Comment: @Vesera Your inner loop runs when the number is already in the dictionary (on the else), this causes it to run multiple times if it already is in the dictionary. On the last run it just sets the value to 1

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Ah I see now, the loops makes the value resets the variable total to 1 because it ran for multiple times. Thank you for the information! Will remember it for the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several ways of counting elements in a list

```
list_to_count = [11, 45, 8, 11, 101, 23, 45, 23, 45, 89, 101]

# Basic dict operations
counts = {}
for x in list_to_count:
    if x not in counts:
        counts[x] = 1
    else:
        counts[x] += 1

# Using .get()
counts = {}
for x in list_to_count:
    counts[x] = counts.get(x, 0) + 1

# Using .setdefault()
# Pretty much the same as .get() but useful when the default is a mutable object like a list or dict
counts = {}
for x in list_to_count:
    counts[x] = counts.setdefault(x, 0) + 1

# Using collections.Counter (the simplest solution...)
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(list_to_count)
```

Comment: Thank You for the complete answer! This really helps me in my study with the Python! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the second for loop, code:

```
n = len(listA)
dictList= {}
for i in range (0, n):
    total = 1
    if listA[i] not in dictList:
        dictList[listA[i]] = total
    else:
        dictList[listA[i]] += 1

print(dictList)
```

Avoiding also the creation of the total variable:

```
n = len(listA)
dictList= {}
for i in range (0, n):
    if listA[i] not in dictList:
        dictList[listA[i]] = 1
    else:
        dictList[listA[i]] += 1

print(dictList)
```

Comment: How about also using `setdefault` or `get` and also forgoing the `range`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat correct, I tried to keep it similar to his approach

Comment: Thank you for the answer, apparently my algorithm still not that good and then this problem occurred. This looks more better and more line efficient than what I did. Thank You!